# GraphQL property names first letter

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, graphql

Im using C# to write GraphQL queries and execute them
i created the schema and everything works fine i get the data back exactly as i want,
but the first letter of the name of the properties gets changed from a capital letter to a small letter.

this is my schema code,

```
var schema = Schema.For(@"
                type user {
                    Indx: Int,
                    UserName: String,
                    Password: String
                }
                type Query {
                    users: [user]
                }
            ",s=>s.Types.Include<Query>());
```

this is the execution code, this execution method works fine returns all the data i want from my tables but instead of returning property names with first letter capitalized it returns property names with first letter small.

```
var json = schema.ExecuteAsync( s => { s.Query = "{ users {indx,userName,password} }"; });
```

this is the result I get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "indx": 593,
        "userName": "string",
        "password": "string"
      },
      {
        "indx": 540,
        "userName": "new test user",
        "password": "1234"
      },
      {
        "indx": 598,
        "userName": "wolv",
        "password": "1234"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

if i change the execution to as follows :

```
var json = schema.ExecuteAsync( s => { s.Query = "{ users {Indx,UserName,Password} }"; });
```

i get an error in return:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \u0027Indx\u0027 on type \u0027user\u0027. Did you mean \u0027indx\u0027?",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 10
        }
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "FIELDS_ON_CORRECT_TYPE",
        "codes": [
          "FIELDS_ON_CORRECT_TYPE"
        ],
        "number": "5.3.1"
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \u0027UserName\u0027 on type \u0027user\u0027. Did you mean \u0027userName\u0027?",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 15
        }
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "FIELDS_ON_CORRECT_TYPE",
        "codes": [
          "FIELDS_ON_CORRECT_TYPE"
        ],
        "number": "5.3.1"
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \u0027Password\u0027 on type \u0027user\u0027. Did you mean \u0027password\u0027?",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 24
        }
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "FIELDS_ON_CORRECT_TYPE",
        "codes": [
          "FIELDS_ON_CORRECT_TYPE"
        ],
        "number": "5.3.1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want the data to be returned like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "Indx": 593,
        "UserName": "string",
        "Password": "string"
      },
      {
        "Indx": 540,
        "UserName": "new test user",
        "Password": "1234"
      },
      {
        "Indx": 598,
        "UserName": "wolv",
        "Password": "1234"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if anyone could encounter the same issue I had but I really wanna help any one who has the same issue.
there is an easy way to do this using aliases,
in your execution of the query

```
var json = schema.ExecuteAsync( s => { s.Query = "{ users {Indx:indx,UserName:userName,Password:password} }"; });
```